# Problems writing type class instances for types determined by a closed type family

Tags: haskell

I tried to model my own enumeration type with type literals, closed type families and a bunch of different stuff. (I know `GHC.Generics` would be probably a better approach, but now I want to know, what is going on.)

Through trial and error (I have to admit that) I finally arrived at this piece of program, which compiles and some things are working (the base case) but the recursion is not:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}


module Wft2 where

import GHC.TypeLits
import GHC.Exts

data Label (l :: Symbol) = Value deriving Eq

instance (KnownSymbol l) => Show (Label (l :: Symbol)) where show = symbolVal

type family Enumerate (a :: [Symbol]) = b | b -> a where
  Enumerate '[] = () 
  Enumerate '[a] = Label a
  Enumerate (a ': b) = Either (Label a) (Enumerate b)

type family CheckEmbedImpl (a :: [Symbol]) (orig :: [Symbol]) (b :: Symbol) where
  CheckEmbedImpl '[] orig b = TypeError (ShowType b :<>: Text " not contained in " :<>: ShowType orig)
  CheckEmbedImpl (b : rest) orig b = (() :: Constraint)
  CheckEmbedImpl (b : rest) orig c = CheckEmbedImpl rest orig c

type family CheckEmbed (a :: [Symbol]) (b :: Symbol) where
  CheckEmbed a b = CheckEmbedImpl a a b

class Embed (l :: [Symbol]) (s :: Symbol) where
  embed :: (CheckEmbed l s) => Label s -> Enumerate l

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (Enumerate '[t] ~ Label t) => Embed '[t] t where embed _ = Value
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Embed '[t] s where embed = undefined
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (Either (Label a) (Enumerate b) ~ Enumerate (a ': b)) =>
  Embed (a ': b) a where embed _ = Left Value
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (Either (Label a) (Enumerate b) ~ Enumerate (a ': b),
                           Embed b t,
                           CheckEmbed b t) =>
  Embed (a ': b) t where embed l = Right (embed l)
```

doing stuff like `embed (Value :: Label "abc") :: Enumerate '["abc"])` and
`embed (Value :: Label "abc") :: Enumerate '["abcd"])` works as expected, but `embed (Value :: Label "abc") :: Enumerate '["abc", abc2"]` gives me errors like

```
*Wft2> embed (Value :: Label "abc") :: Enumerate '["abc", "abcd" ]

<interactive>:13:1: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Enumerate l0’
                     with ‘Either (Label "abc") (Label "abcd")’
      Expected type: Enumerate '["abc", "abcd"]
        Actual type: Enumerate l0
      The type variable ‘l0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression:
          embed (Value :: Label "abc") :: Enumerate '["abc", "abcd"]
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = embed (Value :: Label "abc") :: Enumerate '["abc", "abcd"]
```

I thought the type equality constrain on my third `Embed` instance should handle this. Why isn't GHC able to deduce `l0 ~ '["abc", "abcd"]` and thus
`Enumerate l0 ~ Either (Label "abc") (Label "abcd")`?

Bonus points: If you know about some tutorial, which tries to do stuff like that and has some example, please provide pointers.

Beware it is an injective type family, so it is not to blame on type families being not injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injective type families are fairly new, not very evolved, and fairly buggy.

Note that in the following patterns:

```
Enumerate '[a] = ...
Enumerate (a ': b) = ...
```

if `b ~ '[]` then these patterns both match and the choice between the two is ambiguous. (Also note that while it is obvious to a human that `b` is not `'[]` in `Enumerate '["abc", "abcd" ]`, the compiler doesn't know this a priori - this is precisely what it is trying to prove using injectivity).

This type family still passes the injectivity check because the typechecker knows it is a closed type family and knows that `b` cannot be `'[]` or the previous pattern would have matched. But the actual evaluation semantics of type families don't care at all whether the type family is open or closed. Injectivity doesn't affect evaluation of type families at all; it just allows the typechecker to reduce a constraint like `Enumerate l ~ Label "x"` to `l ~ "x"`.

The solution is to change the last pattern to

```
Enumerate (a ': (b ': c)) = Either (Label a) (Enumerate (b ': c))
```

which makes it 'obvious' that this cannot overlap with the previous one.